# The microphone on of my wireless earbuds do not automatically connect to my computer

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, audio-recording

Issue:

The device has been paired with a windows 10 laptop. After turning the device off and then back on, the microphone does not automatically connect. The audio does connect. The issue is usually rectified by manually disconnecting the headphones and then reconnecting them. I would like to avoid having to do that all the time.

Device:

Jabra Tarah (wireless earbuds)
They have been paired with my computer and they have been updated with the latest firmware.

Fix attempts:
I switch bluetooth in the services page from manual to automatic
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the latest drivers.
I have repaired the device with the computer.
I wanted to avoid having to reset my mobile/network connections so I don't lose the compilation of wifi passwords I have accumulated.

Computer Specs:
Laptop: HP Pavilion x360 - 13-s121ds (ENERGY STAR)
Bluetooth chip: 1x1 802.11b/g/n WLAN and Bluetooth
Manufacturer driver page: https://support.hp.com/sk-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-13-s100-x360-convertible-pc/8499316/model/9072994

Any help would be greatly appreciated.